# Filtering from a pivot table on Django Rest Framework returns all the values

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a project in Django using Django Rest Framework with this models.

job.py

```py
from django.db import models
from .base import BaseModel

class Job(BaseModel):
    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    races = models.ManyToManyField('Race', through='JobRace')
    skills = models.ManyToManyField('Skill')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"
```

race.py

```py
from django.db import models
from .base import BaseModel

class Race(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   ...
    image = models.ImageField(default=None)
    description= models.TextField(blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}
```

and jobRace.py who is the pivot table between jobs a races, I specified instead of letting Django auto generate it because I wanted to add an aditional image field to the pivot table

```py
from django.db import models

from rpg.models.job import Job
from rpg.models.race import Race
from .base import BaseModel

class JobRace(BaseModel):
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, related_name='job_race', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    race = models.ForeignKey(Race, related_name='job_race', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='jobs/')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.job.title} - {self.race.name}"
```

with their serializers

job.py

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from ..models.job import Job
from .skill import SkillSerializer
from .jobRace import JobRaceSerializer

class JobSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    job_race = JobRaceSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = '__all__'
```

race.py

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from ..models.race import Race

class RaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Race
        fields = '__all__'
```

jobRace.py

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from ..models.jobRace import JobRace

class JobRaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    race_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    job_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = JobRace
        fields = ['id', 'race', 'job', 'race_name', 'job_name', 'image']

    def get_race_name(self, obj):
        return obj.race.name

    def get_job_name(self, obj):
        return obj.job.title
```

Now for the views I have a ModelViewSet to get out of the box the basic CRUD functions, but I want to enhance the list method to be able to accept filters so I have this in my job view

job.py

```py
from ..models.job import Job
from ..serializers.job import JobSerializer
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

# Create your views here.
class JobViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Job.objects.all()
    serializer_class = JobSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        # Retrieve query parameters from request
        race = self.request.query_params.get('race')
        # Apply filters to queryset based on query parameters
        if race:
           queryset = queryset.filter(job_race__race_id=race)
        return queryset
```

My objective is that when getting the jobs from one specific race, also getting the image field in the pivot table JobRace but currently with this implementation while Im filtering the jobs well, Im always bringing all the elements from the job_race relationship.

with this url {{baseUrl}}/rpg/jobs?race=5 I should be getting all the jobs with the race 5

But Im getting something like this

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "job_race": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "race": 1,
                "job": 1,
                "race_name": "Elf",
                "job_name": "Warrior",
                "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/jobs/elf-warrior.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "race": 2,
                "job": 1,
                "race_name": "Human",
                "job_name": "Warrior",
                "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/jobs/human-warrior_Po2Du5x.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "race": 3,
                "job": 1,
                "race_name": "Merfolk",
                "job_name": "Warrior",
                "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/jobs/merfolk-warrior.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "race": 4,
                "job": 1,
                "race_name": "Goblin",
                "job_name": "Warrior",
                "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/jobs/goblin-warrior.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "race": 5,
                "job": 1,
                "race_name": "Orc",
                "job_name": "Warrior",
                "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/jobs/orc.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "created_at": "2023-06-27T08:15:23.397062Z",
        "updated_at": "2023-06-27T08:15:23.397062Z",
        "title": "Warrior",
        "races": [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            5
        ],
        "skills": [
            2,
            9,
            11
        ]
    }
]
```

as you can see while is true Im getting the correct jobs because "Warrior" the only job for the race 5 the job_race field brings all the job_races for the warrior with all the other races and Im only interested in bringing the job_race of the Warrior with the race 5 as specified in the viewset

Is there something Im doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you just use `queryset = queryset.filter(races=race)`

Comment: I was doing that, but at some point I changed it to check if I could filter by the pivot table. Anyways that wont solve the issue of not getting the filtered data on the pivot table